# Access resource folder using custom package structure (Maven)

Tags: java, maven, resources

I switched a project of mine to maven. The Problem is that I can't get the resources anymore.

The structure looks like this:

`-src
 -main
  -resources
  -java
   -com
    -test
     -client`

Inside of the resource folder is an image and and fxml file I need to access.

So far I accesed the files using: `Client.class.getResource("FileList.fxml")`.
Client cointains the main method.

Debuging with this command `Client.class.getResource("").getPath()` I get this path: com/test/client.

How do I access the resource folder in a corerct manner?

Comment: I can't see any custom package structure...

Comment: When building a jar the fxml file inside the resources folder should be located at the root of that jar, so `Client.class.getResource("FileList.fxml")` looks correct. Do you have any problems with this?

Comment: Client.class.getResource("FileList.fxml").getPath() gave me back com/test/client/FileList.fxml 
I ended up using Client.class.getClassLoader().getResource("FileList.fxml") which have me the path to the root folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven automatically copies all files in the `src/main/resources` folder to your build directory.

You should see anything in resources at the root of your classpath in the build directory, if everything worked.

For example, if your build directory is 'bin' then you should see:

```
bin
 |--- *.fxml
 |--- <other resources>
 |--- com
       |--- test
              |--- client
                      |--- *.class
```

Change your `Client.class.getResource("FileList.fxml")` call to:

```
Client.class.getResource("/FileList.fxml")
```

which will indicate that the resource is found at the root of the classpath, not the root of the class used to locate the resource.

You noticed that when you tried this: `Client.class.getResource("").getPath()` which returned `com/test/client`. This is telling you without the `/` that the "root" is the directory where that class is located, not the classpath root.

The key is the leading `/` which isn't entirely intuitive.

Comment: Thank you for the fast help. This resolved my issue and I can now access the resources. Thanks!